# wait for data completly load before populate form values using redux-thunk and useSelector

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux

good morning
I am using redux-thunk, and I am obtaining some data via useSelector, because I want to populate a form.

I know that there is a delay obtaining the data in which are undefined, and after I get the data

but at first the form doesn't have a value, maybe because the form is at first getting nothing, and after ,when the data is loaded, the form is not redreshing and updating the value

How can I  make posible to wait for data to be completly loaded and then populate the form?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese

Answer (score 0):

by spliting the logic in two components i was able
one in charge of obtaining data from store by useSelector (selected) and able to render the second component only if selected !== null

and the other component in charge of the form